# No route matches [POST] "users/sign_up"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, routes

new to Rails here. I am wondering if anyone can help me with the problem that I am having. So basically, I am trying to use devise to add user authentication to my app. But every time I tried to submit the signup form, a warning "No route matches [POST] "users/sign_up"" appears on the app.
Here are my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/index'
  root 'home#index'

  #devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'user/sessions' }
  devise_for :users, path: 'auth', path_names:
    { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', password: 'secret', confirmation: 'verification',
      unlock: 'unblock', registration: 'register', sign_up: 'cmon_let_me_in' }

  devise_scope :user do
      get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    end


  resources :workspaces do
    resources :items
  end

end
```

Also, my new.html.erb on the devise/registration looks like:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: new_user_registration_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the `devise_scope :user` block for? Try removing that and see if you still experience the same behavior.

Comment: You've set sign_up to `cmon_let_me_in`.  run `rails routes | grep user` in terminal to see the user routes rails has been configured for.